# Uploading a Django project on Heroku Server

Tags: python, django, heroku, hosting, uploading

I uploaded my Django project to Heroku and I get this error message on the browser as shown on the screenshot

[image]

But when I check the log on the admin I see this message below:

> 2019-05-14T21:26:26.138333+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found

But `gunicorn` is included in my `requirements.txt` file:

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.2.1
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
psycopg2==2.8.2
pytz==2019.1
sqlparse==0.3.0
whitenoise==4.1.2
```

I also have a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`.

Why can't Heroku find `gunicorn`?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you should use *either* `requirements.txt` *or* `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`. They do roughly the same thing, but work with different tooling.

`Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` are a newer standard. If they are present, Heroku installs dependencies using [Pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/). *In this case the `requirements.txt` file is ignored.*

You should either

1. **Choose to use Pipenv.**

   1. Your requirements may already be listed in the `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`, but run [`pipenv install -r requirements.txt`](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics/#importing-from-requirements-txt) locally just to be sure.
   2. Delete your `requirements.txt` with `git rm requirements.txt`.
   3. Commit this change, e.g. `git commit -m 'Switch from pip to Pipenv'`.
   4. Push to Heroku.
2. **Choose to use `pip`.**

   1. Read your `Pipfile` to see if there's anything in there you might need. This file does more than just list dependencies.

      For example, your `Pipfile` may specify a required Python version like `python_version = '3.7'` in the `[requires]` section. This can't be represented in `requirements.txt`, so you'll need to [create a `runtime.txt` file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes#selecting-a-runtime) to specify your Python version.

      You might also want to create a second requirements file for development dependencies.
   2. Delete the `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` with `git rm Pipfile Pipfile.lock`.
   3. Commit, e.g. `git commit -m 'Revert from Pipenv to pip`.
   4. Push to Heroku.